# I'm having a problem including the position of an image within a conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

The problem is in the snippet that begins with the "mouseup' event. I'm trying to get the alert to show when I drag and drop a .tile image, snapping it onto the .amherst div. The image snaps onto the div, but no alert shows.

I'm a real beginner programming in Javascript/jQuery. I did not know how to include the position() function in a conditional, but found examples on the web--but I'm still not sure that I've got that part of it right. And I'm not sure about the use of 'this' here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.container{              
    position:relative;
}
.tampa{
    position:absolute;
    top:418px;
    left:907px;
    width:250;
}
.tile{
    width:47px;
    height:47px;
}
#tile0{
    position:absolute;
    top:590px;
    left:328px;
}
#tileH{
    position:absolute;
    top:590px;
    left:375px;
}
#tileF{
    position:absolute;
    top:590px;
    left:422px;
}
#tileR{
    position:absolute;
    top:590px;
    left:469px;
}
.img{
    width:100%; 
    height:auto;
}
.amherst{
    position:absolute;
    top:417px;
    left:827px;
}
</style>
<script src="jQ/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="jQ/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $("document").ready(function(){
    $('.tile').mouseup(function(){
       if ($(this).position().top==417 && 
           $(this).position().left==827){ 
              alert("Hello");
           }
       });
     $('.tampa').click(function(){
       if ($('.tampa').attr('src')== 'GamePremiseOff.jpg'){
         $('.tampa').attr('src', 'GameConclusionOff.jpg');
       } else if ($('.tampa').attr('src')== 'GameConclusionOff.jpg'){
         $('.tampa').attr('src', 'GamePremiseOff.jpg');
       }
     });
     $('#tile0').draggable({snap:".amherst"});
     $('#tileH').draggable({snap:".amherst"}); 
     $('#tileF').draggable({snap:".amherst"});
     $('#tileR').draggable({snap:".amherst"});
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="amherst"></div>
<div class="container">
  <img src='GameboardCompleteDemo.jpg' width='1620' height='740'>
  <img class='tampa' src='GamePremiseOff.jpg'>
  <img id='tile0' class='tile' src='GameTile0.jpg'>
  <img id='tileH' class='tile' src='GameTileH.jpg'>
  <img id='tileF' class='tile' src='GameTileF.jpg'>
  <img id='tileR' class='tile' src='GameTileR.jpg'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted the alert to show, but it doesn't, and I get no error messages

Comment: log positions  she what are the value

Answer (score 0):

Your  $('.tile').mouseup (with that very strict positioning), is very likely to never call an alert. 
If you want to, you need to call it after draggable has finished, meaning either callbacks or jQuery stop event like in this the demo: http://www.tutorialspark.com/jqueryUI/jQuery_UI_Draggable_Start_Stop_Events.php . Try writing the alert in the stop function, like so:

`stop: function() {
    alert('hi')
 }`